# Subtracting matrices of unequal dimension

Tags: matlab, matrix

When I try to do the following command I get an error.

```
err = sqrt(mean((xi256-xc256).^2))
```

I am aware that the matrix sizes are different.

whos xi256 xc256` gives:

```
  Name         Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  xc256       27x1               216  double              
  xi256      513x1              4104  double
```

I am supposed to negate find the difference of these two matrices. In fact the command given at the top was in the course notes and the course has been running for several years! I have tried googling ways to resolve this error to perform this subtraction regardless but have found no solution. Maybe one of the matrices can be scaled to match the dimensions of the other? However, I have not been able to find any such functions that would let me do this.

I need to find the `RMS` error in a given set of data. `xc256` was calculated through a numerical method, `xi256` gives the true value.

Edit: I was able to use another set of results.

Comment: What is your expected output? Subtract only the first elements?

Comment: How exactly were the values in `xc256` computed? I mean not only by which means (the algorithm), but also, at which nodes? I suspect you need to do some interpolation here...

Answer (score 0):

First check that `xc256` is correctly computed and that you do not have a matrix transposition gone wrong or something like that. Computing the RMS between two vector of different sizes does not make sense, and padding or replicating will get you rid of the error, but is most probably not what you actually want.

Comment: You are correct, but I'm not upvoting because it's not really an answer...rather, it is an implicit request for more background information; a comment would be better suited.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are just two situations that I can think of, I will list them here:

1. The line is wrong (not likely as it looks pretty normal, but make sure to check the book!)
2. The input of the line is wrong

Assuming it is in point 2, again there are two possibilities:

1. `xi256` is of incorrect size (likelyhood of this depends on how you got it)
2. `xc256` is of incorrect size

Assuming it is again point 2, there are yet again 2 likely possibilities:

1. `xc256` should be a scalar
2. `xc256` should be a vector with the same size as `xi256`

From here on there is insufficient information to continue, but check whether you accidentally made it 27 times as long, or 19 times too short somewhere. Just use some breakpoints throughout the code to see how the size develops.